# How to encrypt in node.js and decrypt in browser javascript

Tags: node.js

I have a simple nodeJS program to encrypt plaintext:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var compatEnc = crypto.createCipher("aes-256-cbc", "password");
compatCrypted = compatEnc.update("Message", "utf8", "hex");
compatCrypted += compatEnc.final("hex");
console.log(compatCrypted);
// 0293cf0bdf5323cff809ba406ffc8283
```

I try to decrypt 0293cf0bdf5323cff809ba406ffc8283 on the browser

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/core-min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var nosalt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(0);

    // { salt : null } will generate random salt
    var enc = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("0293cf0bdf5323cff809ba406ffc8283", "password",
    { salt: nosalt });

    console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(enc));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output is blank. Can you tell me what is wrong with my decryption code? Thanks.

Comment: You know if you hardcode the key into the JS, this encryption is going to be useless, right?

Comment: I am just doing a test.

Comment: Did you first try decrypting in node.js? I recommend you try that, and then move to the browser.

Comment: the decrypt with nodeJS is easy:var crypto = require("crypto");

var compatEnc = crypto.createDecipher("aes-256-cbc", "password");
compatCrypted = compatEnc.update("0293cf0bdf5323cff809ba406ffc8283", "hex", "utf8");
compatCrypted += compatEnc.final("utf8");
console.log(compatCrypted);
// Message

Comment: did you look at the npm cryptojs module?  http://npm.im/cryptojs

Answer (score 2):

`CryptoJS` doesn't know that your encrypted text is hex-encoded.

Convert it to a WordArray first using `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(...);`.